# How to convert 8-bit RGBA png image to 16 bpc RGBA png image using java 8?

Tags: java, image-processing, bufferedimage, javax.imageio

I have used BufferedImage class to generate images from pdf. I am getting 8-bit RGBA by using the below-mentioned snippet, but I was unable to convert it to 16 bpc RGBA.

```
int page = 0;
BufferedImage bim = new BufferedImage(100, 100, BufferedImage.TYPE_USHORT_565_RGB);
bim = pdfRenderer.renderImage(page);
String fileName = OUTPUT_DIR + "image-" + page + ".png";
ImageIOUtil.writeImage(bim, fileName, 1);
```

Comment: `TYPE_USHORT_565_RGB` means 16 bits per pixel, with 5 bit red, 6 bit green and 5 bit blue channel, respectively. I think you want 16 bits per *channel*?

Comment: I think you mean 16 bits per Red Green or Blue - why? you have so many colors? that would be 4x16=64 bits per color - Look up the choices on BufferedImage or make up your Own!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To create a 16 bit per sample (or channel) `BufferedImage` and store it as a PNG, you can use the following code:

```
ComponentColorModel colorModel = new ComponentColorModel(ColorSpace.getInstance(ColorSpace.CS_sRGB), true, false, Transparency.TRANSLUCENT, DataBuffer.TYPE_USHORT);
BufferedImage image = new BufferedImage(colorModel, colorModel.createCompatibleWritableRaster(100, 100), colorModel.isAlphaPremultiplied(), null);

if (!ImageIO.write(image, "PNG", new File("test.png"))) {
    System.err.println("Could not write PNG: " + image);
}
```

From the code, I'm assuming you are using PDFBox. If you are using PDFBox, you can use `ImageIOUtil.writeImage` instead of `ImageIO.write`. But you probably want to set the DPI to something more reasonable than `1`...

Also note that `image = pdfRenderer.renderImage(page)` in your code will replace the image, so you can't use that. Try using the `renderPageToGraphics(int, Graphics2D)`method instead:

```
ComponentColorModel colorModel = new ComponentColorModel(ColorSpace.getInstance(ColorSpace.CS_sRGB), true, false, Transparency.TRANSLUCENT, DataBuffer.TYPE_USHORT);
BufferedImage image = new BufferedImage(colorModel, colorModel.createCompatibleWritableRaster(100, 100), colorModel.isAlphaPremultiplied(), null);

Graphics2D g = image.createGraphics();
try {
    pdfRenderer.renderPageToGraphics(page, g);
}
finally {
    g.dispose();
}

if (!ImageIOUtil.writeImage(image, test.png, 72))) {
    System.err.println("Could not write PNG: " + image);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the above solution,
I was trying to generate the png in a specific width and height in pixel but it is cropping the image. Is there any possible way to get in the required pixels?

Comment: @BhuvaneswarSurasani Probably. You need to obtain them from PDFBox, either the pixel size directly, OR the physical size and convert using the DPI of your choice.

Comment: @BhuvaneswarSurasani See this [code in PDFBox](https://apache.googlesource.com/pdfbox/+/309202138bf51cf093dd86b51a67e91f9259cb96/pdfbox/src/main/java/org/apache/pdfbox/rendering/PDFRenderer.java#110) as an example on how to do it.